# Get object synchronously from Parse in Xamarin

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, xamarin, async-await, parse-platform

I am trying to fetch and object from class synchronously by following code:

```
var userName = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Users")
              .WhereEqualTo("UserName","usernameOfUser") ;
var responseUserName = userName.FindAsync();
do {
} while(!responseUserName.IsCompleted || !responseUserName.IsFaulted);
if(responseUserName.IsFaulted){
     Console.WriteLine("Faulted");
}
IEnumerable<ParseObject> result = responseUserName.Result;
```

but 'responseUserName' status is always "waitingForActivation".

if i am doing it wrong please tell the correct way for getting object from class synchronously.

Update: i can not use await. because for await i will have to declare method as async. but i do not want to return control to front end developer(UI developer) until i have result of the query.

Update 2: I can get result by using ContinueWith method. but it does not block the execution until i get results.

```
var userName = ParseObject.GetQuery (Constants.TABLE_USER)
        .WhereEqualTo(Constants.COL_USER_NAME,user.GetUserName());
Users RegisteredUser = new Users ();
var responseUserName = userName.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t=>{
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> result = t.Result;
        if (result.Count() >= 0) {
            Console.WriteLine("Got Records" + result.Count());
        }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: If FindAsync returns a task, you should either call `await userName.FindAsync()` or `userName.FindAsync().Result` to get the actual return value. The tight loop is pointless, .Result will block until a result is available anyway

Comment: By doint this 'userName.FindAsync().Result' i still didnt get the result. i am using while loop just to check the status.

Comment: What did you get? There's no point in checking the status, .Result will block always and return the result of the operation. You already do this with `responseUserName.Result`. If the result is empty, then there were no data to return

Comment: Data is not empty, there are 3 related records in class. i get nothing. app is stuck at this point. and no further processing.

Comment: BTW did you check the [documentation](http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/T_Parse_ParseQuery_1.htm) for FindAsync? The code uses `await`, not a tight loop. Anyway does `result` contain nothing or 3 records? And where did the app get stuck? `.Result` blocks until the asynchronous call finishes, but that's what you asked for anyway. Additionally, there is no point in checking whether the task is faulted: `.Result` will throw an exception if there is an error. You really need to understand how Tasks and `async\await` work though.

Comment: yes i know code uses await. but i can not use await. and i want to .Result to block the asynchronous call. but .Result is never returning any Results(Records). but when i use 'ContinueWith' method it is returning records.

Comment: @BasitZIa: I describe this [classic deadlock situation on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). The best solution **is** to return to the UI; you'll have to design a UI state for "in progress", like a spinner or whatnot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're running into the classic asynchronous deadlock.  The asynchronous code that you're calling is itself calling `await` somewhere (or the equivalent) and it is scheduling continuations that will run in the captured synchronization context.  You're blocking that context with your busywait (or even non-busy wait, when you've tried that).  The asynchronous operation can't complete until you let it run, and you won't let it run until it completes.  Deadlock.

By far the best option is to make this method actually be asynchronous.  If you use any asynchrony at all you should "async all the way up" and make everything asynchronous.  If you aren't willing to do that, then just use synchronous, rather than asynchronous, methods all the way down.